# Seaborn kde plot plotting probabilities instead of density (histplot without bars)

Tags: python, seaborn, histogram

I have a question about seaborn `kdeplot`. In `histplot` one can set up which [stats](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.histplot.html) they want to have (counts, frequency, density, probability) and if used with the `kde` argument, it also applies to the `kdeplot`. However, I have not found a way how to change it directly in the `kdeplot` if I wanted to have just the kde plot estimation with probabilities. Alternatively, the same result should be coming from `histplot` if the bars were possible to be switched off, which I also have not found. So how can one do that?

To give some visual example, I would like to have just the red curve, ie. either pass an argument to `kdeplot` to use `probabilities`, or to remove the bars from `histplot`:

```py
import seaborn

penguins = sns.load_dataset("penguins")
sns.histplot(data=penguins, x="flipper_length_mm", kde=True, stat="probability", color="r", label="probabilities")
sns.kdeplot(data=penguins, x="flipper_length_mm", color="k", label="kde density")
plt.legend()
```

[image: im1 - kde and hist plot]

Thanks a lot.

Comment: When you plot the histogram with a probability (or count) statistic, there's no quantitative relationship between the y axis and the KDE curve. The scaling is entirely dependent on the binwidth in the histogram — change the bin size and the y axis will change, with the entire KDE curve getting scaled up or down with a multiplicative factor. The y axis values of the KDE are only meaningful when `stat="density"`, which will correspond to what you'll get from `kdeplot`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The y-axis of a `histplot` with `stat="probability"` corresponds to the probability that a value belongs to a certain bar.  The value of `0.23` for the highest bar, means that there is a probability of about 23% that a flipper length is between `189.7` and `195.6` mm (being the edges of that specific bin). Note that by default, 10 bins are spread out between the minimum and maximum value encountered.

The y-axis of a `kdeplot` is similar to a [probability density function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function).  The height of the curve is proportional to the approximate probability of a value being within a bin of width `1` of the corresponding x-value. A value of `0.031` for `x=191` means there is a probability of about `3.1 %` that the length is between `190.5` and `191.5`.

Now, to directly get probability values next to a `kdeplot`, first a bin width needs to be chosen. Then the y-values can be divided by that bin with to correspond to an x-value being within a bin of that width. The `PercentageFormatter` provides a way to set such a correspondence, using `ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(PercentFormatter(1/binwidth))`.

The code below illustrates an example with a binwidth of `5 mm`, and how a `histplot` can match a `kdeplot`.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib.ticker import PercentFormatter

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
penguins = sns.load_dataset("penguins")
binwidth = 5
sns.histplot(data=penguins, x="flipper_length_mm", kde=True, stat="probability", color="r", label="Probabilities",
             binwidth=binwidth, ax=ax1)
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
sns.kdeplot(data=penguins, x="flipper_length_mm", color="k", label="kde density", ls=':', lw=5, ax=ax2)
ax2.set_ylim(0, ax1.get_ylim()[1] / binwidth)  # similir limits on the y-axis to align the plots
ax2.yaxis.set_major_formatter(PercentFormatter(1 / binwidth))  # show axis such that 1/binwidth corresponds to 100%
ax2.set_ylabel(f'Probability for a bin width of {binwidth}')
ax1.legend(loc='upper left')
ax2.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

PS: To only show the `kdeplot` with a probability, the code could be:

```py
binwidth = 5
ax = sns.kdeplot(data=penguins, x="flipper_length_mm")
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(PercentFormatter(1 / binwidth))  # show axis such that 1/binwidth corresponds to 100%
ax.set_ylabel(f'Probability for a bin width of {binwidth}')
```

Another option could be to draw a `histplot` with `kde=True`, and remove the generated bars. To be interpretable, a `binwidth` should be set. With `binwidth=1` you'd get the same y-axis as a density plot. (`kde_kws={'cut': 3})` lets the kde smoothly go to about zero, default the kde curve is cut off with the minimum and maximum of the data).

```py
ax = sns.histplot(data=penguins, x="flipper_length_mm", binwidth=1, kde=True, stat='probability', kde_kws={'cut': 3})
ax.containers[0].remove() # remove the bars
ax.relim() # the axis limits need to be recalculated without the bars
ax.autoscale_view()
```