# Legend not showing with barless histogram plot in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, histogram, legend

I am trying to plot a kde plot in seaborn using the histplot function, and removing later the bars of the histogram in the following way (see last part of the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65759931/seaborn-kde-plot-plotting-probabilities-instead-of-density-histplot-without-bar)):

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.histplot(data, kde=True, binwidth=5,  stat="probability", label='data1', kde_kws={'cut': 3})
```

The reason for using `histplot` instead of `kdeplot` is that I need to set a specific `binwidth`. The problem I have that I cannot print out the legend, meaning that

```
ax.legend(loc='best')
```

does nothing, and I receive the following message: `No handles with labels found to put in legend.`

I have also tried with

```
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
plt.legend(handles, labels, loc='best')
```

but without results. Does anybody have an idea of what is going on here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: provide the sample dataset

Comment: I don't know if this is the answer since I don't know what output to expect, but I think you can add this. `ax = sns.kdeplot(data, x="flipper_length_mm", label='kde density')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the label for the kde line via the `line_kws={'label': ...}` parameter.

`sns.kdeplot` can't be used directly, because currently the only option is the default scaling (density).

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

data = np.random.normal(0.01, 0.1, size=10000).cumsum()
ax = sns.histplot(data, kde=True, binwidth=5, stat="probability", label='data1',
                  kde_kws={'cut': 3}, line_kws={'label': 'kde scaled to probability'})
ax.containers[0].remove() # remove the bars of the histogram
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.kdeplot scaled to probability, with legend]